# When I'm going live in vs code it's showing listing directory why?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[see reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXgXZ.jpg).

I'm trying to run files with proper.html extension but still it's showing listing directory instead of running the code. I have faced this issue earlier but that was because I was running the css . But now I'm having the same issue when I'm running the html file. Kindly help

Comment: If it's only a HTML page and not a project that runs on a server. You could simply go to that url "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\firstep\learn.html" instead of 127.0.0.1:5500

Comment: But do I have to do it everytime I go live ? Or is there in any way to fix it permanently

Comment: Well it's sure that way there is nothing live. You add modification and you refresh web page

Comment: Yaa I understood it's just modification but do I have to do it everytime in different files because previously it was all working okay with that  number "127.0.0.1:5500" but now when I restarted today it's showing like that

Comment: If it was working it's another story. Maybe you changed a parameter, moved a file or something like this, I can't be that much of help with the current information

Answer (score 0):

The localhost index is a list of all the paths you have, to access a specific project, you must access it in the following way:

```
localhost/your folder name/path
```